# Can I use tabs instead of spaces in newer versions of Notepad++

Tags: tabs, notepad++

I just downloaded the new version of Notepad++ and I am finding that it is making my Python code edits incompatible with old code due to using spaces instead of tabs. Can I set Notepad++ to use tabs not spaces?

Comment: You should really concede to [pep-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and use spaces. Does Notepad++ convert pressing the tab key into the right amount of spaces?

Comment: @quamrana: Yes, it does.

Comment: You should try to convert all your old code to use spaces and allow Notepad++ to insert spaces for you from now on.